# Facebook credits Graph API call to get order details does not work for test users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits

Per Facebook credits documentation.

Get Order

Gets order details for the specified order_id

API

GET https://graph.facebook.com/[order id]?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

**Note: You must use actual orders when calling the Graph API. Orders from test users will not be processed.**

How do we test this call on dev apps? Is the only way to test this by making real Facebook credits purchases on the app? I would rather user $facebook->api_client->getOrderDetails if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In short. Yes.

I've built a App that in theory works and the transaction completes with me in test mode. But I've not put any real transactions through yet.

It depends what you are selling as the calls Facebook makes to you and expects from you are "as if live".

They just don't get entered into the Graph for Calling by this method.

Comment: What code do you want? Everything pertaining to getting Order Details is in the post above.